# How to get a factory model to persist to MySQL before running Scenario? - Rails 2 & Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber

When I run the following from the console @county = FactoryGirl.create(:state), a new State row is added to MySQL, however when I invoke the same code using a step file only the country & region rows are adde i.e. no state row gets added, not having a state in the db is causing most of my test to  fail & I cannot figure out why.

I am using Rails 2.3.2, cucumber 1.1.4, capybara 1.0.1 & selenium

The factory.rb file:

```
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do
     factory :country do |f|
       f.name 'USA'
       f.country_code 'US'
       f.currency_code 'USD'   
     end

    factory :region do |f|
      f.name 'East Coast'
      f.association :country   
    end

    factory :state do |f|
      f.name 'CA'
      f.association :region
      f.association :country   
    end
```

end

here is the .feature file:

```
Feature: New User Registration

  Scenario: A user should be able to create an account 
    Given there is a state
    And I am on the new user registration page
    ...
```

and the authentication step file:

```
Given /^there is a state$/ do
  @county = FactoryGirl.create(:state)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your authentication step is showing that you're assigning the `:state` object to `@country`...  could that be the reason, or is that a typo?